# How do i ensure my contents are upto date when displayed in iOS UIWebview

Tags: ios, ipad, caching, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I am a Learning management system(LMS) administrator for e-learning courses. My LMS is loaded into a UIWebview of an iOS native app. In this scenario, 
1) How could i make sure my e-learning courses always loads the up to date files and not from cache (i am not in control of iOS App)?
2) For iOS mobile safari browser there is a setting to clear 'cookies and data'. I use this option to clear cache/cookies to make sure the mobile safari browser loads the up to date contents. Is there a similar option available to clear the cache/cookies for websites loaded through UIWebview?

My target platform is iPad with iOS 6